# Concentration of sum of geometric random variables taken to a power

Tags: probability, geometric-distribution, sum

I am interested in techniques for showing the concentration of sum of $n$ iid geometric random variables $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ (number of trials until success), say with success probability $p = 1/2$, each taken to some power $d$. Let $S_n^{(d)} = X_1^d + \cdots + X_n^d$ be the sum of the random variables and let $\mu_d = \mathbb{E}(S_n^{(d)})$. I would like to show something of the form

$$P\left\lbrace S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d \right\rbrace \leq C\exp\left(-f(\delta) n^{\alpha}\right)$$

for some positive constant $C$, some $\delta \geq 0$, and some $0 < \alpha \leq 1$ that may be a function of $d$. For the case that $d = 1$, one is able to use a standard Chernoff type approach to obtain that

$$P\left\lbrace S_n^{(1)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_1 \right\rbrace \leq \exp\left(-g(\delta) n\right)$$

using the fact that $\mu_1 = 2n$ and letting $g(\delta) = (1 + 2\delta) \log\left(1 + 2 \delta\right) - 2 (1 + \delta) \log\left(1 + \delta\right)$. However, it seems such an approach breaks down for $d > 1$ because finding a finite upper bound for $\mathbb{E}\left(\exp(s X_i^d)\right)$, where $s$ is some positive parameter, does not appear to be possible.

I have an alternative approach I worked out when I [posted this problem a few weeks ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086052/184979) but it seems to be a bit loose compared to what can be obtained because it produces a worse result for when $d = 1$ compared to what is shown above.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086052/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520626/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139548/755